# Create Notifications Box

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio-2010

How to show a box in the taskbar?In the Forms i have added the image, but how can I show in the taskbar at the bottom right?

Like This:

[image]

Example:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably want to look into the [NotifyIcon Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.notifyicon.aspx), since you are talking about the Task Bar.

For your notification form, you would target the primary screens lower right corner:

Something like this:

```
notifyForm.Location = new Point(Screen.PrimaryScreen.WorkingArea.Width - notifyForm.Width,
                                Screen.PrimaryScreen.WorkingArea.Height - notifyForm.Height);
```

Make sure your notification has the following property set:

```
notifyForm.StartPosition = FormStartPosition.Manual;
```

Answer (score 0):

Just set its position to bottom right... assuming that is where the notification area is for every user...

Comment: This article seems to have a decent wrapper class to give you that information:
http://winsharp93.wordpress.com/2009/06/29/find-out-size-and-position-of-the-taskbar/ (BTW, I found the link here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1264406/how-do-i-get-the-taskbars-position-and-size)