# How do I get windows taskbar height in WPF application?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

I am trying to get the **height of windows taskbar** from a WPF application. I got this  [How do I get the taskbar's position and size?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1264406/how-do-i-get-the-taskbars-position-and-size) which shows how to find taskbar position but not the height. I got an answer from [how can i get the height of the windows Taskbar?](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/c7b7f8ed-9f58-416e-a6b8-539e9bbd40bd/how-can-i-get-the-height-of-the-windows-taskbar?forum=csharpgeneral) which says

> Use the Screen class.  The taskbar is the difference between its Bounds and WorkingArea properties.

but no code example. If that is correct this should be the height of taskbar. Am I doing it right?

```
private int WindowsTaskBarHeight => Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Height - Screen.PrimaryScreen.WorkingArea.Height;
```

Comment: Why do you want to get the Taskbar height?
It sounds like you actually want to achive something different

Comment: Are you sure the taskbar is not set to auto hide?

Comment: @preciousbetine not sure about that.

Comment: @DenisSchaf I need this for a UI related issue actually.

Comment: This will only work for PrimaryScreen though. If you want the size of any screen, then: https://stackoverflow.com/a/2118993/891715 If your only concern is PrimaryScreen though, you may use System.Windows.SystemParameters.PrimaryScreenWidth (so you don't have to add reference to System.Windows.Forms). Also, user can have the taskbar on the side...

Answer (score 5):

```
var toolbarHeight = SystemParameters.PrimaryScreenHeight - SystemParameters.FullPrimaryScreenHeight - SystemParameters.WindowCaptionHeight;
```

This code worked right for me. I test it in windows 10.

Answer (score 4):

You should be able to use the native `SHAppBarMessage` function to get the size of the taskbar:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    private const int ABM_GETTASKBARPOS = 5;

    [System.Runtime.InteropServices.DllImport("shell32.dll")]
    private static extern IntPtr SHAppBarMessage(int msg, ref APPBARDATA data);

    private struct APPBARDATA
    {
        public int cbSize;
        public IntPtr hWnd;
        public int uCallbackMessage;
        public int uEdge;
        public RECT rc;
        public IntPtr lParam;
    }

    private struct RECT
    {
        public int left, top, right, bottom;
    }

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    protected override void OnSourceInitialized(EventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnSourceInitialized(e);

        APPBARDATA data = new APPBARDATA();
        data.cbSize = System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.SizeOf(data);
        SHAppBarMessage(ABM_GETTASKBARPOS, ref data);
        MessageBox.Show("Width: " + (data.rc.right - data.rc.left) + ", Height: " + (data.rc.bottom - data.rc.top));
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes. I tried with it. The result is same as my code.

Comment: And that result is?

Comment: Result is correct. But always get height from primary monitor (in case of multiple monitor).